# How do I use boolean logic to make this if-statement more concise in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, string-matching, boolean-logic

I want to extract job titles that consist of either "back-end", "back end" or "backend" from json data of a website. I managed to do so with the following code:

```
if "back-end" in jobtitle.lower():
            print(jobtitle)
if "back end" in jobtitle.lower():
            print(jobtitle)
if "backend" in jobtitle.lower():
            print(jobtitle)
else:
            continue
```

The example output is as below:

```
Software Back-End Developer
(Senior) Back-end PHP Developer
Backend Developer (m/w/d)
Back End Developer
Front-End / Back-End Developer (m/w/d)
```

How do I make it more concise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you *have* to use `if ... in`? Another solution would be to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

`back[\-\s]?end` [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/fhyYoU/2)

Explanation:

- `back`: Match "back"
- `[\-\s]`: Any of these characters: `-` or `<whitespace>`
- `?`: Zero or one of the previous
- `end`: Match "end"

Run it in Python like so:

```
rexp = re.compile(r"back[\s\-]?end", re.IGNORECASE)
if re.search(rexp, jobtitle):
    print(jobtitle)
```

Comment: I would suggest  using `re.IGNORECASE` as well.

Comment: Good point, although if OP is testing `jobtitle.lower()` anyway it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular-expression here would be optimal, because it's quick and it will solve it in one row.

However, if you want to use an `if ... in` statement for each option, then you can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to compare them in the same statement:

```
x = """Software Back-End Developer
(Senior) Back-end PHP Developer
Backend Developer (m/w/d)
Back End Developer
Front-End / Back-End Developer (m/w/d)""".splitlines()

for row in x:
  if any(i in row.lower() for i in ["backend", "back end", "back-end"]):
    print(row)
```